# Cannot boot from USB in UEFI mode

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, manjaro

I have prepared a USB bootable for Manjaro using Universal USB Installer 1.9.9.0 available on Windows. However, booting into the USB fails. After getting to the boot devices menu I select the flash drive, then the screen flashes black as if something were going to happen but I land back at the boot menu. Selecting Widows Boot Manager boots the device normally. I have enabled UEFI only and disabled secure boot and fast boot. If instead I enabled Legacy mode I am able to boot into the USB however this still seems like a problem and I would like my installation to be done in UEFI mode as I understand that it is better.

Previously I had installed Ubuntu on this laptop using a USB (in UEFI mode I believe) so I am unsure why I am unable to boot into a USB now. Currently the laptop is running windows and I just got it back from Lenovo after sending it in for repairs. It is possible there are motherboard issues, which is what I am trying to rule out here.

The laptop in question is a Thinkpad T495.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried preparing your USB stick using RUFUS / Easy2Boot / YUMI ? I have always had good luck using those utilities to prepare my flash drives.

I have a true triple boot myself (Win10 / Win7 / Ubuntu) but it's been several years since I set it all up... I just remember it was a bit of a pain and required AHCI being ON, secureboot being disabled, and RAID disabled too IIRC. Even still, I had to use a 3rd party tool to fix up my bootloader(s), and I had to go back into my BIOS and manually add at least 1 entry in my (UEFI?) bootloader list so that it would show up to be bootable.

Comment: I tried an Ubuntu image and that worked actually. It might be the software I used to prepare the image like you suggested.

Comment: I would also check out: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ to read up on the topic of bootloaders and/or UEFI with regards to Linux. Manjaro isn't quite as user friendly as Ubuntu, so it may not have proper UEFI boot support baked into its image. I believe Easy2Boot can get around that if you are not sure how to modify the install image/flash disk. Like I said, it's been a while for me, but I intend to dump Ubuntu soon and switch over to Manjaro myself soon.